# GVRVideoViewer showing pink screen, but still has sound

Tags: ios, swift

Swift 4, iOS 11. Trying to implement a simple embedded video player for a 360 video.  With the following code, I get a hot pink video player screen, with sound still playing as expected. The GVRVideoView is first set in Interface Builder, as a GVRVideoView. When run, the viewer is showing up exactly where it should. Is there something I'm missing in the implementation that would cause this?  Or is there something else (video?) that I need to be looking at instead? Thanks, this is driving me nuts ...

```
class VideoPlayerViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// Player View contents:
@IBOutlet weak var videoVRView: GVRVideoView!
@IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    enableLocationButtons()
    let videoFilePath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "/Videos/videoFileName", ofType: "mp4")
    let videoFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoFilePath!)
    videoVRView.load(from: videoFileURL, of: .embedded)
...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using GVR SDK version 1.2 as i found that the latest version have problems regarding video playback while this version is very stable regarding the video playback

pod 'GVRSDK', '1.20.0'